# Upload a file from URL then send it from angular to springboot

Tags: angular, url, upload

I'm searching for a solution specially to upload a file from URL, I haven't found a solution by myself.
For upload I have already what it should do the job later. But most important I have an url, from where I have to upload one audio file to spring later.

Can someone help?

Comment: What i need to know if it possible to download in background, not on the navigator a file and store it in a path where we can make it downlable for costumers.

Answer (score -1):

I finally got to download the audio file from URL by `http.get(url)` then I passed `bufferarray`as option to the request, after this I used this code to transform the file and upload it to my springboot directory:

```
 this.acapelaSRV.downloadAudioAsBlob(url).subscribe(
        data => {
          let blob = new Blob([data], { type: "audio/x-wav"});
          let namefile = this.utilitySRV.makerandom(12)+'_'+this.nomfichieraudio+'_'+this.client_connected.id+".wav";
          var file = new File([blob], namefile);
          this.uploadSRV.pushFileToStorage(file).subscribe(
            success => {
              console.log('File Saved to local');
              UploadDone = true;
            },
            error => {
              console.log(error);
              UploadDone = false;
            }
          )
          if(UploadDone){
            this.saveaudio({id: null, nom: this.nomfichieraudio, nom_storage: namefile, text: this.text_To_Speech, langue: this.selected_language, voix: this.selected_voice, id_client: this.client_connected.id})
          }
        },
        error =>{
          console.log(error);
        }
      )
```